Cmake error for ROS - cannot find the package
I follow the tutorial of Turtlebot3 to launch the turtlebot into the Gazebo environment. I am using OS - Ubuntu 20.04.1  LTS, ROS version - Noetic, Gazebo Version: 11.14.0. I received error while doing catkin_make
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "turtlebot3_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    turtlebot3_msgsConfig.cmake
    turtlebot3_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "turtlebot3_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "turtlebot3_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "turtlebot3_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.

How can I fix this error?

Try installing turtlebot3 messages using the following command
sudo apt install ros-noetic-turtlebot3-msgs

